# streamlit-webrtc not working in aws server

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, streamlit, stun

i tried to deploy my streamlit-webrtc app on aws server using docker . but i got the below error

```
Error: navigator.mediaDevices is undefined. It seems the current document is not loaded securely. "
```

after read some articles i added below line to configure the stun server

```
rtc_configuration={  
        "iceServers": [{"urls": ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}]
    }
```

but now i am facing the same issue again .

app.py

```
from streamlit_webrtc import webrtc_streamer

webrtc_streamer(key="sample", rtc_configuration={  # Add this line
        "iceServers": [{"urls": ["stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"]}]
    })
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.11.6

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8501

CMD streamlit run app.py
```

requirements.txt

```
streamlit-webrtc
```

app - http://13.48.59.97:80